# insert into temporary table not working in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

i have the following stored procedure:

```
create temporary table logData (table_name varchar(50), column_name varchar(50), changed_date date, changed_by char(10), old_value varchar(50), new_value varchar(50))

insert into logData SELECT table_name, column_name, changed_date, changed_by, old_value, new_value FROM log WHERE changed_by=empId AND changed_date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate

UNION

SELECT "reservation_flight", column_name, changed_date, changed_by, old_value, new_value FROM reservation_flight_log WHERE changed_by=empId AND changed_date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate

UNION

SELECT "ticket", column_name, changed_date, changed_by, old_value, new_value FROM ticket_log WHERE changed_by=empId AND changed_date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate

UNION

SELECT "passenger_record", column_name, changed_date, changed_by, old_value, new_value FROM passenger_record_log WHERE changed_by=empId AND changed_date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate

select * from logData order by changed_date;
```

In the above sql select statement `empId`, `startDate` and `endDate` are the input parameters for this stored procedure. This is showing error please help? Thank You!

Comment: format `MySQL code`, instead of posting plain text

Comment: What error is it showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing two semicolons: one at the end of the first statement and another at the end of the before-last line. You may rewrite it like the following:

```
CREATE temporary TABLE logData (table_name   varchar(50), 
                                column_name  varchar(50), 
                                changed_date date, 
                                changed_by   char(10), 
                                old_value    varchar(50), 
                                new_value    varchar(50));

INSERT INTO logData 
   SELECT table_name, column_name, changed_date, changed_by, old_value, new_value 
   FROM log 
   WHERE changed_by=empId AND changed_date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
UNION
   SELECT "reservation_flight", column_name, changed_date, changed_by, old_value, new_value 
   FROM reservation_flight_log 
   WHERE changed_by=empId AND changed_date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
UNION
   SELECT "ticket", column_name, changed_date, changed_by, old_value, new_value 
   FROM ticket_log 
   WHERE changed_by=empId AND changed_date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
UNION
   SELECT "passenger_record", column_name, changed_date, changed_by, old_value, new_value
   FROM passenger_record_log
   WHERE changed_by=empId AND changed_date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate;

SELECT * FROM logData ORDER BY changed_date;
```

Comment: I have used semicoloms also but it is not working but when i run without insert into statement it works but i need to store data in temporary table to sort them datewise.. please help me?

Comment: i forget to use begin ... end statement inside the procedure and it was showing error. Now it worked. Next problem is when i execute the above procedure in phpmyadmin it displays result but when i execute from java it returns nothing.. Please help ..?